# Hacked WP, regex link removal

Tags: regex, wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress website which got hacked by a "Pharmahack". I have done multiple scans and checked multiple files they all seem fine.

My task now is to remove all of the spam links and text, at the moment I'm doing it manually from a DB dump but there are 300 instances of the offending content.

It is all contained within `<div style="position:absolute; left:-3841px; top:-3137px;">` the left and top are variable.

Does anyone know a regex that could remove all the content within this div?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please explain why this is downvoted?

Comment: generally I would not recommend trying to cleanup your site. They might have hidden a small backdoor which can be very hard to detect. Apart from that regex is not suited for parsing html pages. I would use a scripting language like Ruby combined with Nokogiri

Comment: I am just taking a break from searching for the moment, so I decided to clean up the DB then continuing to search for the offending files. And the regex provided below by bjfletcher worked perfectly in removing all the spam within the posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the width and height will always be negative, and that the content within the offending `<div/>` snippets don't have any inner `<div/>` snippets:

```
s/<div style="position:absolute; left:-\d*px; top:-\d*px;">.*?<\/div>//g
```

Here's the regex in play: https://regex101.com/r/eV1kN7/1

Comment: Thanks a million, saved me hours :) Will mark correct in 3 mins

Comment: It happened to me once (many years ago!) and it wasn't nice, and so it's only my pleasure to help.